# Found animals in Y'rushalayim going straight to the Mikdash without waiting for the owner?

Tags: animals, korban, lost-and-found, tractate-shekalim

If one finds an animal (of certain species) in or around Y'rushalayim [when the *Beis Hamikdash* is up and running] one can assume it was destined to be brought as a *karban* and give it to the custodians of the *Beis Hamikdash* materials to be offered as whichever *karban* suits it. ([*Sh'kalim* 7:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Shekalim.7.4))

Also, if one finds an animal in public there is a protocol to follow to decide initially if it is likely to have been lost - as opposed to being far away from but in the care of its owner - and then to determine whether and how its owner should be identified for the purpose of restoring the animal. ([*Baba M'tzi'a* 2:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Bava_Metzia.2.9))

**At what point does the assumption that the animal near *Y'rushalayim* is destined for service kick in vis-à-vis the protocol for returning lost animals in general?**

- Is the latter forgone in favor of the former?
- Does the initial check for signs of ownership (e.g. being saddled, being fenced in, etc.) need to be surpassed before collecting it and shipping it up the hill to the *mikdash*?
- Does the second stage of attempting to find the owner and [all that it entails](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77145/3) have to transpire before this conclusion can be reached?

---

The commentaries on *Sh'kalim* mention the possibility of the owner appearing, but only in discussing the opinion of R' Y'huda and not the main rule in the *mishna*. So it's unlikely that this rule circumvents the general *hashavas aveda* ones. Maybe the owner's status only matters because R' Y'huda's case is that of the *karban pesach*, which needs to be tied to the correct owner for reasons unrelated to *hashavas aveda*?

Comment: Yachin: "דתלינן דמירושלים יצא, ושם רוב הבהמות קרבנות הן" if that's the proven majority - why not?

Comment: As I understand it, in all cases we follow the majority of what is acceptable in the same area - if the majority is observant we return, if the majority is Goyim we don't, if the majority bring to a king - we bring to the king. We can rely on an assumption, that once there are known rules a person gives up his hope. So seemingly there's no contradiction. **An important note**: in any case, the final resolution is always left to the court, the owner can sue the returner and sometimes rightfully win, if the conditions are different.

Comment: How is it different from עיר שרובה גויים, that overrides the סימנים? That's עיר שרובה קרבנות.

Comment: @AlBerko It sounds like your answer would be that this _din_ is in fact a special case of the usual laws of _hashavas aveda_. I'd be happy to have that as an answer, with a justification!